# Error when importing scikit-learn library: [WinError126] specified module could not be found

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, scipy

I've install the scikit-learn module using pip, but when I try to import it in a file, I get the following error:

```
File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
  File "X:\...\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 80, in <module>
    from .base import clone
  File "X:\...\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .utils import _IS_32BIT
  File "X:\...\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from scipy.sparse import issparse
  File "X:\...\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\scipy\__init__.py", line 136, in <module>
    from . import _distributor_init
  File "X:\...\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\scipy\_distributor_init.py", line 61, in <module>
    WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))
  File "X:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 364, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
```

I've looked everywhere and haven't been able to find a solution. Please help.

Comment: Hi, does the module sklearn show when you use this command: "pip list | grep sklearn" ?

Comment: @KimTang Hi, running that command gives the following output: `sklearn                  0.0`